# docker container exited immediately after python script execution

Tags: python, docker

docker container exited immediately after python script execution:

docker run -t -i -v /root/test.py:/test.py zookeeper python test.py
(test.py starts zookeeper service )

The command is successful but exits immediately with out starting container. I could NOT start the container with "docker start container id".

Manually running "python test.py" is successful inside container but not during "docker run ...."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just starting the server is not enough.  When the CMD exits, so does the container.  Thus, if you start a service that's a daemon, you need to keep your process alive.  This can be achieved by, for example, tailing the service log file.  supervisord is another way to run processes and keep the CMD alive.

For example, you might do

```
CMD /test.py && tail -F /var/log/zookeeper.log
```

Running from the commandline you could do something similar

```
docker run -t -i -v /root/test.py:/test.py zookeeper bash -c "python test.py && tail -F /var/log/zookeeper.log"
```

Comment: Excellent it worked. I know it's executing and getting out, but didn't know how to handle the situation. Thank u.

Comment: There should be a check mark next to the answer.  You can just click it.