# Python dev with Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I would like to be able to run a python module within his dedicated container after I updated the code.
So, I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src/ .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "test.app"]
```

I would like to be able to run the container but also mount the /src/ folder to update the code and run again the module. But I don't want to run and build the image each time.
So I wrote the following docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 test:
  build:
   context: .
  volumes:
  - ./src/:/app
```

It seems to work but after running the `python3 -m test.app` the container is logically exiting.

Is there a way to keep it open when docker-compose, to be able to edit the python code and rerun the module directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker container exited immediately after python script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497580/docker-container-exited-immediately-after-python-script-execution)

Comment: If you run your application in your host development virtual environment, does the Python interpreter keep running, or does it exit?  Does it behave differently in Docker?